# Why doesn't this show my canvas when i run it?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

So i was working on a code to show my logo i want to make out of lines and polygons in a canvas, and after i tried to run it: surprise, the canvas doesn't show up. What did i do wrong?

```
from tkinter import *

class Logo(Frame):
    def _init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)

        logo = Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)
        logo.pack(in_=self)

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.showLogo()

    def showLogo(self):
        self.logo = Logo().pack(side=TOP, pady=100)

root = Tk()
root.title("K-80.1")
root.configure(background="#7E607E")
root.geometry("760x500")
app = App(master = root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have a typo in `Logo`: `_init__`.

Comment: BTW, `.pack` returns `None`, so `self.logo = Logo().pack(side=TOP, pady=100)` sets `self.logo` to `None`. Also, in the `Logo` class definition, you are using the global `root`. It would be better to pass the `master` as a parameter to `showLogo` and to `Logo.__init__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Mac, I know that there can be some issues with color. I don't know if it relates to creating a canvas. If this is the issue, I know that there are ways to get around it, as I have heard. I just don't know them. I myself have just tested the code (I have Windows) and got this...

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ7JD.png)

When Changing the '_init__' typo I get this...

[After Typo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZEXc.png)

This may have to only do with the typo or maybe not? I don't know what you're seeing.

Comment: That RESULT is just the root window, which the OP set to that colour.

Comment: Yeah thanks, it was that typo that ruined it for me hehe. I kinda got so used to writing that syntax that i couldn't even think i could make such an error. 
Thanks a lot!